# Why is$ (2n)! = \Pi k^{2n}$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Why is $$(2n)! = \Pi^{2n} k $$

I know that $n! = \Pi k $

$k=1 $to$ 2n $

My Problem is that this was the Solution and don't know how this shall be true

Comment: What is limits of product ?

Comment: @Zubzub I think this is supposed to be [Gauss’s notation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GammaFunction.html) $\Pi(x)=\Gamma(x+1)$

Comment: Could this be just a confusion induced by bad typesetting? We have $n! = \prod_{k = 1}^n k$ and $(2n)! = \prod_{k = 1}^{2n} k$. With bad enough typesetting, that might look a bit like $\prod k^{2n}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you write $n!=\prod k$, I assume the $k$ in your question goes from $k=1$ to $k=n$.

---

This isn't even true for $n=1$...

$$(2\cdot 1)! = 2! = 2$$

while

$$\prod_{k=1}^1 k^{2\cdot 1} = 1^2=1$$